# How can I get the celery daemon to run on Ubuntu 16.04 using systemd?

Tags: 16.04, services, systemd

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and systemd to run celery as a daemon. I have created the unit file also but i am not able to run celery as a service. Why is this error happening?

Here are the contents of `/etc/systemd/system/celery.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=celery
Group=celery
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/celery
WorkingDirectory=/srv/weaver/src
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the `/etc/default/celery` file:

```
ENABLED="true"
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="main:celery_app"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/srv/weaver/src"
CELERYD_OPTS=" --queue=weaver  --time-limit=100000 --concurrency=2"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERY_D_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery2/%N.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
# Change Celery Beat
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/srv/weaver/src"
# Log files
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/celerybeat.log"
# Celery Beat Log files
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/celerybeat.pid"
# Scheduler for celery
CELERYBEAT_OPTS=" --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celerybeat.pid  --schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule"
```

This is the output of the running service:

```
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-01-12 17:12:32 IST; 2min 17s ago
  Process: 18561 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c ${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES}    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18540 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c ${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES}    -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}    --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FIL
 Main PID: 18555 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 12 17:12:30 fb01 systemd[1]: Starting Celery Service...
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 sh[18540]: celery multi v3.1.23 (Cipater)
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 sh[18540]: > Starting nodes...
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 sh[18540]:         > worker1@fb01: OK
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 systemd[1]: Started Celery Service.
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 sh[18561]: celery multi v3.1.23 (Cipater)
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 sh[18561]: > worker1@fb01: DOWN
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem not long ago.

- Using `CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE` in `/etc/default/celery` file was helpful for me.
- Also check if you have the user named `celery`. You can run celery under another unprivileged user. I launch celery under my own user.

Below is my file `/etc/default/celery`:

```
ENABLED="true"
CELERYD_NODES="celery_worker"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/path/to/my/project"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryd"
CELERY_APP="celeryd:celery"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="my_user_name"
CELERYD_GROUP="my_user_name"

CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1

CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
```

Here is my `/etc/systemd/system/celery.service` file word by word:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
Group=group
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/celeryd
WorkingDirectory=/opt/celery
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Note that, based on your `celery.service` script (the `ExecStart` part) your environment  settings such as `CELERYD_CHDIR`, `CELERYD_USER`, `CELERYD_GROUP` may be ignored by celery, and should define directly in `.service` file.

Comment: @mrdaliri is that because celery ignores environment variables? Or, put another way, celery doesn't support those configuration options as environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom, turned out to be permissions.

In my case something like:

```
chmod o+x /srv/weaver/src
```

sorted it.

Note: That this is **not** the best way to enable the required permission but that's not pertinent to this answer.