# log file permission error

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I am trying to run a command :

```
celery -A main:celery_app beat --logfile=/var/log/celery/celerybeat.log
```

It shows permission denied error:

```
stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/celery/celerybeat.log
```

but i think i have correct permissions. When i run `ls -la /var/log/celery/celerybeat.log`

I got

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 celery celery 0 Jan 12 14:18 /var/log/celery/celerybeat.log
```

and for `celery` command i checked in `systemd` file, it has `celery` defined as its `user` and `group`. Why is there such an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [celery daemon using systemd not running in ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/871035/celery-daemon-using-systemd-not-running-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @CelticWarrior how is it even a duplicate?? that question was about celery daemon not running properly. but here daemon is running properly  but unable to access file and thats why `file permission error`

Comment: Accessing `/var` needs root.

Comment: @CelticWarrior celery daemon is also running as `celery` user and logging into `/var/log/celery/` daemon does not have root access. how is that running then?

Comment: @CelticWarrior how can i debug the cause?

Comment: I don't know celery, but first thing which comes to mind - when you start it with your command, is it running as celery  user or your user ?

Comment: @user596137  it running as celery user( it should i guess because in its ystemd file user and group is defined as celery) . what is odd is if celery process creates this log file in the mentioned directory, it does not have write access to it . it has only read access for `celerybeat.log`